# Jquery UI dialog - Flash content shining through on scroll in Safari

Tags: flash, jquery-ui, safari, dialog, scroll

I have a problem similar to this:

[How to stop Flash content shine-through jQuery UI Dialog in Firefox on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602678/how-to-stop-flash-content-shine-through-jquery-ui-dialog-in-ff-windows)

..but only in safari and only when when I'm scrolling the content inside the dialog. When the dialog appear, everything is fine. But when you start scrolling, with the mouse wheel or by dragging the bar, the flash content start to shine through and come back. For example:

start: Fine
scroll one step: Flash bleeding through
scroll second step: Fine
scroll third step: Flash bleeding through
etc.

When in modal "mode", the modal background come over the dialog, but is still over the flash.

Chrome and Firefox works fine. I tried "wmode=transparent" and "wmode=opaque" and check the z-index, but nothing come up.

Help?

Flash code with swfobject:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
   var flashvars = false;
   var params = {wmode: 'opaque', bgcolor: '#FFF4D5'};
   var attributes = false;
   swfobject.embedSWF("chat/logo.swf", "logo", "250", "100", "9.0.0", "../expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
              </script>
```

Dialog opening thingy:

```
function openAdminDialog(buttons) {

 $("#admin-dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 925,
  height: 500,
  modal: true,
  title: 'Title',
  buttons: buttons,
  close: function() { 
   $('#admin-dialog').remove();
  }
 });
 $('#admin-dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

EDIT: SWFObject translate to this (from Safari console):

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="chat/logo.swf" width="250" height="100" id="logo" style="visibility: visible; "><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFF4D5"></object>
```

Comment: Also experiencing this issue - it seems to be only occurring in Safari 5, and only with certain machines.

Not using the jQuery UI dialogs however, but normal HTML elements and divs that are layered over the top of a Flash movie, so I suspect it's more of a Safari issue than anything to do with jQuery UI dialogs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't found a solution yet, but if the same thing is happening without Jquery, it may be Safari fault indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, only on Safari for Mac, works fine for all other browsers. Even select, text and background images where showing through (flickering, to be exact).
The only way I could fix it was hiding the flash container, and showing it again on close.

```
$(e).click(function(){
    $(popup).dialog({       
        close: function(){
            $(flashElem).show();
        }
    });
    $(flashElem).hide();
    return false;
});
```

Not optimal, but works.